# Import initial data to the database without dropping the tables with hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, database, hibernate

I'm using a Spring MVC, Hibernate config over maven. On the application starts I'm importing initial data to the database from import.sql(includes some insert operations) using following configurations.

```
 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
```

According to the documentation **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** property should be **create** or **create-drop** to execute the import.sql file . When I use that values for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property it executes the sql file but it drops the exiting tables and delete the previous data.

I want to import the initial data without dropping the previous tables as sometimes I have to run the application more than one time while keeping the data in the database.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Change ddl auto to `update`

Comment: I also faced for same issue, but couldn’t able to do through hibernate , is there any workaround for this anyone can suggest . I tried with ddl auto to update . But didn’t work .